# We should change "What does 'beta' mean?" page

Tags: discussion, bug

I just found and read the [What does "beta" mean?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta) page. As it is currently written, many points in this article are not accurate according to my understanding. Let me highlight some sections that I think should be rewritten or be removed altogether.

> This site was created through the open democratic process at Stack
> Exchange Area 51.

Definitely not the case.

> In early beta, the elections will be held to appoint moderators.

Will it?

> There is no set amount of time for a site to remain in beta; it will
> be in beta for as long as necessary to reach critical mass, with
> periodic evaluations that help communities know where they stand and
> what they need to work on.

I think I read somewhere that this site has already set a date to lunch for public. As for the periodic evaluations, I don't know if we have one yet.

So, I think those sections may need some kind of adjustment.

Comment: 1) Re: Area 51, yes, this is a special case. 2) Re: election, yes, [beta now also goes through pro-temp elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102760/241919) rather than the old CM appointment. 3) Re: beta, note that there are 2 types of beta: private and public. Private beta usually runs for 4-5 weeks, while [public beta can be more than 7 years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/241919).

Comment: The local copy of this article should be hidden and the links changed point to a meta or blog post to be created before the 26th (site launch).

Comment: Thanks for flagging I will get this updated.